# How to upgrade TensorFlow to 2.0 in Julia?

Tags: tensorflow, julia, tensorflow2.0

```
julia> print(tf.VERSION)
1.4.2
```

I've found methods to upgrade in python but can't find any solution for Julia.

Comment: The last commit to tensorflow.jl was well over a year ago so I wouldn't hope for too much. The Julia community focuses more on Flux and knet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `Tensorflow-2.0` official API/package available for `Julia` as of now. Note that even implementation of `Tensorflow` for `Julia` which is [TensorFlow.jl](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl) was not official one and it was community based with the [approach recommended by the TensorFlow maintainers](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/guide/extend/bindings.md) and also it was just `Julia` wrapper for `Tensorflow`.

As stated [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs) in official documentation, for `Tensorflow-2.0` [API Stability](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/versions) is promised for Python only.

If you're looking for Deep Learning frameworks/packages in `Julia` then use [Flux.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl) or [Knet.jl](https://github.com/denizyuret/Knet.jl) as they're active and pure `Julia` based solutions. If you want to write gpu code directly in `Julia`, there are [JuliaGPU](https://github.com/JuliaGPU) packages available, additionally you can refer [generic gpu kernels](http://mikeinnes.github.io/2017/08/24/cudanative.html).

If your intent is to use `Tensorflow-2.0`, then suggest you to use Python package.